# How does MySqlCommand.LastInsertedId work?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net

In a project of mine, I had to get the last inserted ID from the database so that I can sync newly inserted data with in memory data without doing a `SELECT * FROM my_db;` query i.e. I am doing a `SELECT * FROM my_db WHERE id=new_index`.

Now, I know that MySQL, which I'm using, supports the query `select last_insert_id();`, so I figured I would just make that command and execute it. But upon digging into C# (the programming language that I'm using for the project) I've discovered that the `MySqlCommand` has a `LastInsertedId` field.

Now what puzzles me is that I expected the getter of the field to just do the same `select last_insert_id();` query, but upon looking at the logs from MySQL, I see no such query being made at all.

So my question is, how does `MySqlCommand.LastInsertedId` know what ID was assigned to the tuple that I'm inserting when the ID is auto generated by the MySQL server?

Comment: Have you enabled logging **all** the queries executed on that server?

Comment: @e4c5 I executed the `SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';` command so yes. Anyway, I see that I have my question answered. Thanks for the interest in the subject anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the MySQL server responds to the client software (in your case it's Connector/Net) after an UPDATE query, it sends a [so-called `OK_Packet` over the tcp (or socket) connection](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/packet-OK_Packet.html). That packet contains the last_insert_id value.

On the server it's available incidental to any INSERT query without another query, and so the wire-protocol handler just throws it in to the response packet.

The client software extracts that value from  the packet and presents it to your application software on the [LastInsertedId](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/html/P_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_LastInsertedId.htm) property.

Answer (score 3):

If MySQL successfully executes a query requested by a client, then MySQL send an [OK_Packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/packet-OK_Packet.html) as a response.

In the payload of the OK_Packet MySQL includes the last inserted id (see documentation linked above):

```
Type        | Name           | Description
------------|----------------|-----------------------------------
int<1>      | header         | [00] or [fe] the OK packet header 
int<lenenc> | affected_rows  | affected rows 
int<lenenc> | last_insert_id | last insert-id
...
```

[MySQL bug #65452](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=65452) indicates that LastInsertId method reads the data out of a packet:

```
public int GetResult(ref int affectedRow, ref int insertedId)
{
...
insertedId = (int)packet.ReadFieldLength();
...
}
```

This indicates that the LastInsertId gets the value from the OK_Packet. On the server no `select last_insert_id()` is executed to populate this value into the OK_packet, this is why you do not see any such query in the query log.

Comment: Thank You very much for a detailed reply. You've really explained everything I wanted to know. The only reason why I chose @O. Jones answer as accepted is because he answered quicker and said basically the same thing.