# How does PDO's LastInsertId actually work?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

On the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) it's stated

> Returns the **ID of the last inserted row**, or the last value from a sequence object, depending on the underlying driver.

Where if there's no `$name` variable passed as the first parameter to `PDO::LastInsertID()`, it'll check the last row that was inserted into the database. The state of this function also can be determined to work or not by the drivers that are stated, if you're using `MySQL` you're fine as that's heavily supported, but if you're using a database that doesn't support the `OID` or `AUTO_INCRAMENT` table definitions, `PDO::LastInsertId()`'s most likely not going to work.

That's all good and makes sense, but how is this achieved?

I understand `PDO` is just another abstraction layer to database connection, but we're also talking about the `mysqli_insert_id` function as well.

My idea of this method was that there's a cache (`not on PHP's side`), which I later discovered was true when reading this bit of code from `warezthebeef at gmail dot com` on the manual page.

```
// Assume $dbh connection handle is already established
$sql = "INSERT INTO product (product_name) OUTPUT INSERTED.product_id VALUES (?)";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array('widgets'));
$temp = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo "<pre>",print_r($temp),"</pre>";
```

This would display:

```
Array
(
    [product_id] => E1DA1CB0-676A-4CD9-A22C-90C9D4E81914
)
```

This is cause the table in the database would contain the row `product_id` and in the `SQL` you're stating to output that row after inserting, which would be the `id` for more common-ground terms, and if using `AUTO_INCRAMENT` would just be a single number. (you can read more into it by looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999396/how-do-i-use-an-insert-statements-output-clause-to-get-the-identity-value)) (this is also achievable with the `RETURNING` SQL keyword)

So, in a way if we didn't want to use the `PDO::LastInsertID()` method, we could just use:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (name, country) OUTPUT INSERTED.id VALUES (?,?)";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute( ['jack', 'Australia'] );
$temp = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $temp['id']
```

Which should output the new ID we just inserted into the database, noting that we use an `AUTO_INCRAMENT` primary or OID column.

So in my head (that's why I'm asking this question) PDO could be caching the data in `PHP's Temp` then retrieving or writing over it when the method is called, possibly adding the `RETURNING id` or such to it, but that's not the way it'd work since it's based on the `OID` column.

**I answered half of the question - I'm just wondering how the method actually stores the last ID or pulls it**

Thanks!

Comment: I would guess it uses mysql's last insert id function. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: side note to this you can select the `id` directly with the statement `$lastInsertId = $dbh->lastInsertId();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact implementation depends on the driver. I can only describe how it works for MySQL because that's what I'm familiar with.

As we described in the answers to [How does MySqlCommand.LastInsertedId work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381892/how-does-mysqlcommand-lastinsertedid-work/) question:

If MySQL successfully executes a query requested by a client, then MySQL sends an [OK_Packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/packet-OK_Packet.html) as a response.

In the payload of the OK_Packet MySQL includes the last inserted id (see documentation linked above):

```
Type        | Name           | Description
------------|----------------|-----------------------------------
int<1>      | header         | [00] or [fe] the OK packet header 
int<lenenc> | affected_rows  | affected rows 
int<lenenc> | last_insert_id | last insert-id
...
```

On the server no `select last_insert_id()` is executed to populate this value into the OK_packet. The driver retrieves the last inserted id from the packet and PDO in turn retrieves the value from the driver.

Comment: And if you really want to retrace it in the code, I'd suggest starting at https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.1.0/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_driver.c#L288 and track it down to https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.1.0/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_wireprotocol.c#L2839

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :-)